Why do Jacobian matrices with zero eigenvalues fail to predict long-term behavior?
I have been studying non-linear systems of equations and how one can attempt linearization by forming a Jacobian matrix. I understand how the matrix approximates the system since you can think of the linearization as a Taylor series where we ignore the terms of higher order than the linear ones: If $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,y)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y)$ then

\begin{align*}
                \frac{d}{dt}(x-x^*) &\approx f(x^*,y^*) + \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*)\right](x-x^*) + \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)\right](y-y^*) \\
                \frac{d}{dt}(y-y^*) &\approx g(x^*,y^*) + \left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*)\right](x-x^*) + \left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)\right](y-y^*)
            \end{align*}

So at an equilibrium point $(x^*,y^*)$ we have $f(x^*,y^*)=g(x^*,y^*)=0$

\begin{align*}
            \frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}
            x-x^* \\ y-y^*
        \end{pmatrix} &\approx \begin{pmatrix}
            0+\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*)\right](x-x^*) + \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)\right](y-y^*) \\
            0+\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*)\right](x-x^*) + \left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)\right](y-y^*)
        \end{pmatrix} \\
        &= \begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*) \\
            \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*) & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
            x-x^* \\ y-y^*
        \end{pmatrix}
        \end{align*}

so the method of approximation is intuitive to me. The question I have is why the approximation becomes less precise with Jacobian matrices with zero eigenvalues? I know that this is true since I have seen examples where the Jacobian does not predict the correct type of equilibrium (like at $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^3$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=y-y^2$ at point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ the Jacobian does not predict a nodal source), but have not gotten an intuitive explanation as to why it is true. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

can you find an example in one dimension?

If the first derivative in a Taylor series is $0$, then you need to go to higher order terms to understand the system.  (Unless the system really is the zero function, in which case, no amount of taking extra terms will provide more information.)
Your Jacobian is telling you about the dynamics on the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to nonzero eigenvectors.  However, the Jacobian is "acting like a zero first derivative" for the subspace spanned by eigenvectors corresponding to zero eigenvalues.  That means we need to look at higher degree terms for that subspace to find out what's actually happening on it.  (And maybe the system really does zero-out that subspace and maybe it doesn't -- we won't know until we look at those higher order terms.)

Thank you! How does this generalise to any eigenvalue with zero real part? Since I've been told this is the case for purely imaginary eigenvalues, but I haven't been able to recreate it - any system that I try to recreate this in seems to have the sample solutions locked in a stable orbit, similar to how the Jacobian predicts.

Let's agree that we have an idea what zero eigenvalues are doing.  Other eigenvalues with zero real part do correspond to eigenvectors whose evolution is (complex) revolution.  For real dynamics, we expect either growth or shrinking and to see what the radius of that orbit is doing, we need to look at higher terms in the Taylor series.  The first order expansion is telling us what it can, but if we want to know more, we need to examine a bit more about the function.
